# Modifying existing C++ code for running on GPU using CUDA

Tags: c++, stl, cuda

I have a **class A** which implements a complex algorithm and has many public/private member functions. This class uses objects of another **class B** which implements 3D-Vector operations and so has many member functions (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`==`,`!=` etc.).

**Class `A`** is designed to run on CPU with multiple CPU threads. Both classes use many STL containers such as pair, vectors(of object pointers), string, maps, multimaps, sets, queues etc. and uses bit true data types such as `uint32_t`.

Now I want convert one of the algorithm(member function) of **class `A`** to a CUDA Kernel which can be executed by 16 CPU threads and thereby running 16 kernels concurrently on a Kepler GPU. This means member functions of **class A** and **class B** will need to be executable on GPUs. Also any STL specific stuff I will either need to do using Thrust or write my own CUDA code to implement that container/algorithm

In order to do so, I can think of two approaches

- Modify my existing C++ code where I mix host and device functions
- Create CUDA C++ code(classes) from scratch using my existing C++ code

With C, it is fairly easier to modify the existing code. But for C++ this is fairly complex exercise and it becomes more complex if existing code uses STL heavily.

So question is what is the best way to go about modifying my C++/STL heavy code to make it CUDA ready ?

**--UPDATE--**

- Member functions of C++ class cannot be marked as `__global__` to make it a kernel. This implies Kernel function always needs to be a non-member function which can be called by a member function.

Comment: I think so concrete examples would help here

Comment: Last time when I did this (having to port a C++ / std heavy code to CUDA) I went full C with serialize / deserialize approach . (basically I regarded CUDA as a separate object that takes data in and gives data out on computing intensive sections). I did this on a raytracer, so every primitve was serializable . All scene management , loading etc was done in CPP while heavy stuff was done by CUDA. If such approach is appropriate for your needs I suggest you take it since it will help you decouple from CUDA and then you can implement a Strategy Patern .

Comment: Well, what I am looking for is a good design pattern using which I can reuse my CPU code as much as possible and port only specific member functions as CUDA Kernel and device functions. And while doing all this, make sure my code remains readabale and gives me ability to switch between CPU and CUDA execution flow conveniently. I am still working on devising such a pattern. Will share some results soon!

Answer (score 2):

I found this [article](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/developing-portable-cuda-cc-code-hemi/) very helpful, basically, the idea is that you put some macros before your functions to make them compilable on both host and device.

Comment: Links are likely to expire. You should put relevant parts in your answer.